# What does "there" mean when people say "No surprise there?"

Tags: word-usage

[image]

> No surprise **there**.

I know the `no surprise` part, just the `there` — what's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

> What does “there” mean when people say “No surprise there?”

It means "about that matter", "about that situation", "in that case".
Depending on the sentence, it might also mean the "there" which is juxtaposed with "here" - like "over there", referring to location.